# Not able to save Jenkins Job after changes , no error is visible

Tags: performance, jenkins, load-testing, jenkins-job-dsl

**Precondition**: 
Jenkins 2.277.4 
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20

**Problem**:
I have a Freestyle Job
For First time all the done changes are saved (At this moment 'Save' and 'Apply' buttons are at the mid bottom of the page)
Next time If I come to do some more changes and try to save, it doesn't work AND no error at all neither in browser 'console' or 'network' (At this moment 'Save' and 'Apply' buttons are at the left bottom of the page)

This issue is similar to this issue raised in Jenkins jira https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65142

Comment: It will be: JENKINS-65142. Read the [upgrade guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.277/#configuration-form-modernization) and follow the procedures.

Comment: Got the solution :)

"publish performance test result report" plugin is the culprit ! When I disabled this plugin, it solved the problem.



Source: (mentioned by @IanW.. thanks man :) )
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.277/#upgrading-to-jenkins-lts-2-277-1

Although it has not a precise solution but it says that you have to disable unused or corrupted plugins (which plugin... its not mentioned, you have to do hit and trial)

Comment: Also, have you looked at using [Warnings NG](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/) plugin (not sure it's covered).

Comment: @IanW I am new here not sure how to mark yours answer as 'answered'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be same as: [JENKINS-65142](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65142), as a result of tables to divs migration [JENKINS-64072](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64072).

This will affect any Jenkins upgrades to 2.277.1+

Read the [upgrade guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.277/#configuration-form-modernization) and follow the procedures. Check the [broken plugins dashboard](https://issues.jenkins.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa?selectPageId=20741)

It may still be a matter of trial and error if your plugin has not already been identified. Be sure to upgrade all plugins which you can first, then diagnose.