# Does upgrading Jenkins.war file cause Environment variables to not be populated?

Tags: jenkins

I upgraded to the latest version of the jenkins.war file. The jobs run but when it sends and email the environment variables are not populated. Some of the variables I use are

[$BUILD_STATUS] - $PROJECT_NAME - $BUILD_NUMBER $BUILD_ID

Is there a know issue with this ?

Comment: Not directly, but lots of plugins broke upgrading to 2.777.1+. Review similar [advice to here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67445686/598141). Insufficient serials to answer more.

Comment: I also upgraded jenkins recently, it resulted in so much of issues.This was one of the issue i faced as yours, aligning all the plugins with its compatible versions solved my problem.

Comment: so i am in the process of updating the plugins that need updating and will see how that goes . thanks for the update

Comment: so if i try to install the latest plugin for email-ext , it says it is being used by another process ?                                                                                                                                    Also:   java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Jenkins\plugins\checks-api\WEB-INF\lib\checks-api.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)