# Jenkins upgrade to 2.270

Tags: jenkins

After I upgraded Jenkins from 2.250 to 2.270 I noticed that Jobs configuration looks different and the SSH settings that are configured for each job are missing. I see multiple artifactory configuration tabs and job notifications/Source Code management/Build triggers/Build environment tabs are missing (please see the attached screen shots).

Not sure how to restore the SSH settings and disable artifactory configuration in the jobs that don't use artifactory.

[image]

After upgrade:

[image: after_upgrade]

Comment: Not sure why you be using the weekly release stream instead of the LTS stream and the  not upgrade to latest. Nevertheless, you seem to be affected by the same issue when [moving from LTS 2.263.x to 2.277.1+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67445686/598141). Same advice appliea, plus switch to tbe LTS stream.

Comment: Thank you, Ian. will look into switching to LTS.